# oncreate function doesnt start

Tags: android, android-activity

Trying to launch another activity from my main activity using a button i placed on my main activity, now when the button is clicked it prints "call activity" and so it works fine, but when the second activity is launched it seems like it doesn't execute oncreate method, as it doesn't print "start" and doesn't call GetCar(); method. The only thing it does is to show the xml.

button that launches  second activity (print "call activity" is working fine)

```
public void allCars(View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars_menu);
    System.out.println("call activity");
}
```

second activity code (doesn't print "start" or call GetCar().)

```
public class CarsMenu extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    public static String[] carId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars_menu);
        System.out.println("start");
        GetCar();
    }
}
```

second activity xml (can't see viewlist probably because i can't set text (doesn't call GetCar()) .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

all of my activity is on the manifest and i'm not getting any errors on logcat.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="btnCarClick"
        android:text="Refresh" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MlistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start your Activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Just setting the content view is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Your starting your second Activity in the wrong way, and you only change your view in your first Activity.

In order to change activity you need to call

```
startActivity (Intent intent)
```

for more info you can read on

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are just changing the content UI of current activity. As

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars_menu);
```

does only that. In real your 2nd activity is never started even. For starting second activity you should do

```
Intent i = new Intent (Activity1.this, CarsMenu.class);
startActivity (i);
```

Make sure you have added CarsMenu activity to your Android Manifest.

Comment: whem im trying to do that i getting the java runtime exception unable to start activity componentinfo.